# split a numpy array both horizontally and vertically

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, split

What is the most pythonic way of splitting a NumPy matrix (a 2-D array) into equal chunks both vertically and horizontally?

For example :

```
aa = np.reshape(np.arange(270),(18,15)) # a 18x15 matrix
```

then a "function" like

```
ab = np.split2d(aa,(2,3))
```

would result in a list of 6 matrices shaped (9,5) each. The first guess is combine hsplit, map and vsplit, but how the mar has to be applied if there are two parameters to define for it, like :

```
map(np.vsplit(@,3),np.hsplit(aa,2))
```

Comment: (6,9,5) should be the shape of the resulting matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, it would be good but (9,5,6) would do, too, or even a "non-NumPy" list of six NumPy arrays, like in many other NumPy functions would be good enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `np.split` & `np.concatenate`, the latter to allow the second split to be conducted in a single step:

```
def split_2d(array, splits):
    x, y = splits
    return np.split(np.concatenate(np.split(array, y, axis=1)), x*y)

ab = split_2d(aa,(2,3))

ab[0].shape
Out[95]: (9, 5)

len(ab)
Out[96]: 6
```

This also seems like it should be relatively straightforward to generalize to the n-dim case, though I haven't followed that thought all the way through just yet.

**Edit:**

For a single array as output, just add `np.stack`:

```
np.stack(ab).shape
Out[99]: (6, 9, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @EFT!

Answer (score 9):

Here's one approach staying within NumPy environment -

```
def view_as_blocks(arr, BSZ):
    # arr is input array, BSZ is block-size
    m,n = arr.shape
    M,N = BSZ
    return arr.reshape(m//M, M, n//N, N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,M,N)
```

**Sample runs**

1) Actual big case to verify shapes :

```
In [41]: aa = np.reshape(np.arange(270),(18,15))

In [42]: view_as_blocks(aa, (9,5)).shape
Out[42]: (6, 9, 5)
```

2) Small case to manually verify values:

```
In [43]: aa = np.reshape(np.arange(36),(6,6))

In [44]: aa
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

In [45]: view_as_blocks(aa, (2,3)) # Blocks of shape (2,3)
Out[45]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [30, 31, 32]],

       [[27, 28, 29],
        [33, 34, 35]]])
```

If you are willing to work with other libraries, [`scikit-image`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) could be of use here, like so -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks as viewB

out = viewB(aa, tuple(BSZ)).reshape(-1,*BSZ)
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [103]: aa = np.reshape(np.arange(270),(18,15))

# @EFT's soln
In [99]: %timeit split_2d(aa, (2,3))
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.3 µs per loop

# @glegoux's soln-1
In [100]: %timeit list(get_chunks(aa, 2,3))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.7 µs per loop

# @glegoux's soln-2
In [111]: %timeit list(get_chunks2(aa, 9, 5))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.39 µs per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [101]: %timeit view_as_blocks(aa, (9,5))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 µs per loop
```

Please note that I have used `(2,3)` for `split_2d` and `get_chunks` as by their definitions, they are using that as the number of blocks. In my case with `view_as_blocks`, I have the parameter `BSZ` indicating the block size. So, I have `(9,5)` there. `get_chunks2` follows the same format as `view_as_blocks`. The outputs should represent the same there.

Comment: Fix `aa` -> `arr`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Divakar ! Thanks a lot @glegoux!

Comment: @NickPanov Always a pleasure!

Comment: Do you inverse row and  line to split into blocks ??

Comment: @glegoux Check out the last paragraph in my post. I guess that should clarify your doubts.

Comment: @Divakar @glegoux gets credit for `get_chunks` (typo). Also, the interesting thing with the %timeit results is that `np.split` is what really slows mine down. `view_as_blocks` and `list(get_chunks())` are both faster than even a  single call to `np.split`.

Comment: `%timeit view_as_blocks(M, (9,5))` 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.27 µs per loop no way

Comment: @glegoux `%timeit get_chunks2(M, 9, 5)` would be wrong as that's getting a generator, not the actual outputs. Correct one would be : `%timeit list(get_chunks2(M, 9, 5))`. Updated the timings with your second approach.

Comment: `%timeit list(get_chunks2(M, 9, 5))` 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.04 µs per loop
you win good code I upvote

Comment: I had to log in to say thanks to you @Divakar . Without this answer I had have spent unfruitful hours because I really didn't know how to my phrase my problem into Google search terms. Fortunately, I stumbled on this post and it's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

To cut, this matrix (18,15) :

```
+-+-+-+
+     +
+-+-+-+
```

in 2x3 blocks (9,5) like it :

```
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
```

Do:

```
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np

M = np.reshape(np.arange(18*15),(18,15))

def get_chunks(M, n, p):
    n = len(M)//n
    p = len(M[0])//p
    for i in range(0, len(M), n):
        for j in range(0, len(M[0]), p):
            yield M[i:i+n,j:j+p]

def get_chunks2(M, n, p):
        for i in range(0, len(M), n):
            for j in range(0, len(M[0]), p):
                yield M[i:i+n,j:j+p]

# list(get_chunks2(M, 9, 5)) same result more faster
chunks = list(get_chunks(M, 2, 3))

pprint(chunks)
```

Output:

```
[array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
       [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34],
       [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49],
       [ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64],
       [ 75,  76,  77,  78,  79],
       [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94],
       [105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
       [120, 121, 122, 123, 124]]),
 array([[  5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
       [ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24],
       [ 35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
       [ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54],
       [ 65,  66,  67,  68,  69],
       [ 80,  81,  82,  83,  84],
       [ 95,  96,  97,  98,  99],
       [110, 111, 112, 113, 114],
       [125, 126, 127, 128, 129]]),
 array([[ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
       [ 25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
       [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44],
       [ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59],
       [ 70,  71,  72,  73,  74],
       [ 85,  86,  87,  88,  89],
       [100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
       [115, 116, 117, 118, 119],
       [130, 131, 132, 133, 134]]),
 array([[135, 136, 137, 138, 139],
       [150, 151, 152, 153, 154],
       [165, 166, 167, 168, 169],
       [180, 181, 182, 183, 184],
       [195, 196, 197, 198, 199],
       [210, 211, 212, 213, 214],
       [225, 226, 227, 228, 229],
       [240, 241, 242, 243, 244],
       [255, 256, 257, 258, 259]]),
 array([[140, 141, 142, 143, 144],
       [155, 156, 157, 158, 159],
       [170, 171, 172, 173, 174],
       [185, 186, 187, 188, 189],
       [200, 201, 202, 203, 204],
       [215, 216, 217, 218, 219],
       [230, 231, 232, 233, 234],
       [245, 246, 247, 248, 249],
       [260, 261, 262, 263, 264]]),
 array([[145, 146, 147, 148, 149],
       [160, 161, 162, 163, 164],
       [175, 176, 177, 178, 179],
       [190, 191, 192, 193, 194],
       [205, 206, 207, 208, 209],
       [220, 221, 222, 223, 224],
       [235, 236, 237, 238, 239],
       [250, 251, 252, 253, 254],
       [265, 266, 267, 268, 269]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, I used `np.array_split` together with transforming the matrices. So let's say that I want it split into 3 equal chunks vertically and 2 equal chunks horizontally, then:

```
# Create your matrix
matrix = np.reshape(np.arange(270),(18,15)) # a 18x15 matrix

# Container for your final matrices
final_matrices = []

# Then split into 3 equal chunks vertically
vertically_split_matrices = np.array_split(matrix)
for v_m in vertically_split_matrices:
    # Then split the transformed matrices equally
    m1, m2 = np.array_split(v_m.T, 2)
    # And transform the matrices back
    final_matrices.append(m1.T)
    final_matrices.append(m2.T)
```

So I end up with 6 chunks, all of which are the same height and the same width.